# How can I override an already overridden template by jbot?

Tags: plone, zope

I'm making a Plone theme that uses `plonetheme.bootstrap` as base skins.

I want to customize the portaltab viewlet, so I use `plone.app.themeplugin`'s override plugin and add my `plone.app.layout.viewlets.sections.pt` into `overrides` folder.

That didn't work, while other template does. Later I found out that it's because `plonetheme.bootstrap` had already overridden it.

So how can I override an already overridden template? And how is a BrowserLayer picked when there are so many?

Comment: The key here is layer and you must subclass plonetheme.bootstrap layer in your theme to be "more accurate". You need to confirm from someone (z3c.jbot authors) that it supports layer inheritance correctly first, though.

Comment: Recent versions of z3c.jbot do indeed support associating your template overrides directory with a layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mikko Ohtamaa and David Glick for the tip and the information.

I subclassed plonetheme.bootstrap layer instead of the default one and it worked. 
You'll also need to add that layer into Diazo theme's browserlayer through `manifest.cfg`, eg:

```
[theme:browserlayer]
layer1 = lanlankernel.theme2013.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific
```

There must be a way, may be a patch in `plone.app.themeplugin`, to make sure the layer that's auto-generated by the browserlayer plugin is on top of the lookup chain. But the current solution works for me so I marked the question as answered.