# How do I sub classing a layer to overide an already overriden page template by jbot?

Tags: plone, zope

Similar to the problem in this question ([How can I override an already overriden template by jbot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209392/how-can-i-override-an-already-overriden-template-by-jbot)) I am using a base skin that contains jbot overides to template files that I want to overide again.

My product is based on a theme called responsive theme. This theme contains overrides I wish to change.

skins.xml:

```
<skin-path name="buyspoke-theme" based-on="Responsive Theme">
```

configure.zcml

```
<browser:jbot
    directory="templates"
    layer=".browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific" />
```

the jbot overrides in 'responsive theme' are taking priority. I realize from the question above the solution is to 'subclass a layer', I suppose my question is how? An idiot guide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide another jbot registration in another product:

```
<browser:jbot
      directory="templates"
      layer=".your.product.CustomInterface" />
```

Then your interface must be something like this:

```
from .... import IThemeSpecific

class CustomInterface(IThemeSpecific):
    pass
```

And you must register a [browser layer](http://developer.plone.org/views/layers.html#add-on-layer) for you product.

So: your new interface is subclassing the interface from the theme.

Another way is to use [z3c.unconfigure](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure).

**Note**: I fear that both ways will replace all of the templates inside the original folder (so I think you can't simply customize a single template).

Comment: Thanks for your solution keul, has done the job perfectly. zc3.unconfigure only supports zope 3.8 so wasn't an option for me.